# recently purchased products

Tags: magento

How to display recently purchased products on dashboard after login in magento?

Comment: Please be more specific in all your questions. Remember to include details such as which version you're using and what you have previously attempted. Read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Answer (score 1):

1. for backend you need to make a block that gets the order collection (by status) filtered with date range and iterate over them by getting their item collection and display those. Alternate way would query products and join order information and filter by date
2. for frontend it is much the same but a filter is needed to strict the orders by customer id